# Stuck with a number theory problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Here is a problem I don't even know how to approach: For arbitrary integers a,b,c which satisfy $(a,b)=(b,c)=1$ and $b>1$ there exist infinitely many integers n such that $ab^n+c$ is not prime. Any help with this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the notation $(a,b)$ referring to?

Comment: @Myridium:  it is the $\gcd$ of $a$ and $b$

Comment: Hint: What are the possible values of $(a,c)$? See what can be done with that

Comment: @lhf: No, if $n$ has an odd factor we know $2^n+1$ is not prime.  That is an infinite set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to show $\gcd(b, ab+c)=1$, from which using [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)
$$b^{\varphi(ab+c)}\equiv 1 \pmod{ab+c} \Rightarrow b^{\varphi(ab+c)+1}\equiv b \pmod{ab+c} \tag{1}$$ or 
$$ab^{\varphi(ab+c)+1}+c\equiv ab+c \equiv 0 \pmod{ab+c}$$ which means 
$$ab+c \mid ab^{\varphi(ab+c)+1}+c$$
but, using $(1)$, this is also true for
$$ab^{2\varphi(ab+c)+1}+c\equiv ab^{{\varphi(ab+c)+1}}+c \equiv ab+c \equiv 0 \pmod{ab+c}$$
and by induction
$$ab^{k\cdot\varphi(ab+c)+1}+c \equiv 0 \pmod{ab+c}, \forall k \geq 1$$
i.e. there will be infinitely many $ab^n+c$ divisible by $ab+c$ and thus not primes.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $p$ is a prime factor of $ab+c$, then by Fermat's little Theorem, $p$ is a prime factor of $ab^{(p-1)N+1}+c$.